# Yahoo Finance: sold stock

Tags: stocks

Don't know how to mark the stock sold on Yahoo finance. I marked a minus sign before the shares numbers but yahoo says it is a short. Please help. Thanks...Young

Answer (score 1):

If you sell a stock in your Yahoo portfolio, you'd just reduce the amount by the number of shares that you sold (or remove it if you sold the lot) in the "Holdings" tab. You *could* put in any gains as cash if you want a total portfolio value, but there's no concept of tracking transactions in Yahoo to my knowledge.